# Union Of Two SQLiteQuery In A same Cursor

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new in android application development.
I want to do UNION of two query in a same cursor.

```
    public Cursor getAll() {
        return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
                "SELECT _id,x,y from XYZ where _id=" + id+" UNION SELECT _id,z from lmn where _id=" + id, null));
    }
```

Comment: does a standard UNION not work? Can you post come code please

Answer (score 2):

Use [UNION in sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) query to connect more than one query and execute that query as rawQuery in android